# SSRS formatting row colors based on attribute values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a problem with my report. I want to change colors of rows in my report based on what value is inside specific columns.
For example I have 6 columns: name, description, from currency code, to currency code, exchange rate, last import date.

I want to format my table like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!last_import_date.Value<>Today(), "Red", "LimeGreen")

=IIF(Fields!name.Value= "HMRC UK" & Fields!last_import_date.Value<>Today(), "Red","LimeGreen")
```

I want to join those two conditions but I dont really know how to.

I forgot to mention that in the second condition I have to change condition connected to date. It should check if field last_import_date value is within month that we currently having.

Comment: replace "red" in first condition with second whole IIF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=IIF(Fields!name.Value= "HMRC UK" 
         AND datepart("M",
                      Fields!last_import_date.Value) =datepart("M",
                                                               Today()), 
     "LimeGreen",
     IIF(Fields!last_import_date.Value=Today(), 
         "LimeGreen",
         "Red"))
```

If the field is HMRC and the date this month then GREEN, if the date is today then GREEN, else RED

Comment: The condition should do something like this:
(If name = "hmrc uk" and date is within this month then we have a green row else red) and for the rest of rows name doesnt matter but if we have date <> from today then red else green. I tried your exprestion but it worked for attribute with completly different name.

I meant only the second half of this expression worked.

Comment: I think It was what I searched for. Thank You! You were a great help!